# Validation on Login in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I query SQL to display an error message? Suppose the user types in his username and password. When he types a wrong username, an "Error: Invalid Username" will appear. And when he types in a wrong password, an "Error: Invalid Password" will appear.

P.S. I'm a beginner in CodeIgniter and PHP.

Comment: read codeignitor documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below:

1) Get a single record from the users table you have using the user entered username.

2) If you got a result, then go to step 3 , else display a message, **Invalid username **.

3) If the use is found, then check compare the passwords. If passwords matches, then login user else display **Invalid password error**

For database operations, you can use CI active records which are good and easy to use. 
For CI database operations, please read this

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html

Hope this will help.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your reply @altafhussain , I got an idea 'bout this one. I'm working it on right now. Big Help.

Comment: you are welcome. If this is the answer you were looking for, then please mark it as accepted answer. Thank you